# Why so many duplicate strings in EXE binary?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, linker, mingw

**Background:** After switching to CMake I later noticed that the executable had tripled in size to 1.3 MiB. (On Windows using MinGW64) Using a tool to browse the EXE I noticed some obvious errors by looking at the included strings, such as accidentally using debug mode and statically linking one of the libraries. And after linking with `-s` it got down to an acceptable 200 KiB.

**Issue:** However I'm still seeing a lot of duplicate strings. For example:
`GCC: (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.2.0`
Why is it repeated 50 times, can't it just share the same string instead of duplicating it?

What made me more curious is a lot of weird strings which are also duplicated, such as:

```
([^_]
X[^_]A\A]
fffff.
UWVSH
AWAVAUATUWVSH
```

Full list here: https://pastebin.com/YBdhau0Y Any ideas to where these strings come from and what they are used for? Some of them are postfixed versions of another one, like `UWVSH` is the last part of `AWAVAUATUWVSH`. They do not appear in any header files, but I found them in the object file for a class that just did some math on rectangles.

**Questions:**

- Why cannot these strings be shared in the file? Or how do I make them?
- What is the purpose of including the compiler info?
- What are all the strange strings I'm seeing for?

Note: I'm estimating about 5 KiB savings by removing the duplicates, so I'm mostly just curious.

**UPDATE1:**
Compiling `int main(){}` with `gcc -Os -s -fno-ident` gives a 17 KiB executable which contains the string `AUATUWVSH` twice. It also contains the GCC identifier string 26 times.

Comment: You can remove the gcc version string by adding `-fno-ident` in the compilation step.

Comment: Have you tried using link time optimization?

Comment: @ssbssa It removes 15 of the 50, leaving 35 of them. I'm guessing that they are from included libraries since I'm actually seeing two versions of GCC. I'm not going to try recompile every library with `-fno-indent` though.

Comment: @crezefire I have yet to try LTO, but I will look into it at some point since staticly linking with LTO seems to make a lot of sense on Windows where you don't share libraries anyway.